# Extend JWT TTL while user is logged in

Tags: php, angular, laravel, jwt

I have a project build with a Laravel 5.5 backend and Angular 4 front-end.

I am using JWT tokens to authenticate my users and all is working well apart from the refresh tokens, refreshing a token is not as simple as its made out to be. If I refresh my token, due to all my requests being async, requests can happen between the time I send for a new token and it getting back, causing issues.

Another solution suggested is to just extend the lifespan of the JWT every time they use it.

Say my JWT has a TTL of 60 minutes and a user logs in at 9:00, and then they make a request at 9:30, at this request I want to extend the current token by another 60 minutes so that then that token will expire at 10:30 and not at the original 10:00